# Hide legends in Chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I want to hide legends in Chart.js in label and tooltips.

I am using v2.5.0

I am trying this way but its not hiding legend in tooltips

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="250"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function(e){ 
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var data = {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June1", "July"],
        datasets: [
            {
                fill: false,
                lineTension: 0.3,
                pointRadius: 15,
                pointHitRadius: 15,
                pointHoverRadius: 15,
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                spanGaps: false,
            }
        ]
    };  
    var options={
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
               label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                      return tooltipItem.yLabel;
               }
            }
        }
    };
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: data,
        options: options
    });
}
</script>
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kncvoxce/2/)**

I have also tried in global values like this

```
    Chart.defaults.global.legend= false;
```

But legends are still shown in tooltips, Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear: You don't want to display the labels at the x-axes or you don't want to show the legend within the tooltip (the month as headline)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by adding `displayColors:false` in tooltips option like this

```
    tooltips: {
        displayColors:false,
        callbacks: {
           label: function(tooltipItem) {
                  return tooltipItem.yLabel;
           }
        }
    }
```

Now the legend are not shown, I hope it helps someone with similar issue.